# What's the simplest database implemented on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

For each row in a database1 , compare the data in the cell at index 1 to each row in an existing database2 at cell index 1, and if there is a match, then change the value of the cell at index2 of database2 from 1 to 0

2 NSDictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is generated and consumed in app then CoreData. 
Otherwise sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

[Sqlite](http://slite.org). Among other options like CoreData, sqlite databases are portable and could then without any modifications be used on Android, Mac OS, Windows and many other platforms.